# How to get from there to there?

Tags: calculus

I have this expression :
$$-\sin { x } (\sin { x } +1)+\cos { x } \times \cos { x } =\quad -2\times sin(x)^{ 2 }-sin(x)+1$$
I am not getting at all how to get from left to right, even if I know that is has something to do with $sin(x)^{2}+cos(x)^{2}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $\cos^2(x)=-\sin^2(x)+1$ on the LHS, then the RHS will emerge after you expand $-\sin x(\sin x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$=-\sin x(\sin x+1)+\cos^2x=-\sin^2x-\sin x+\cos^2x=$$

$$=-\sin^2x-\sin x+\overbrace{1-\sin^2x}^{=\cos^2x}=-2\sin^2x-\sin x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-\sin { x } (\sin { x } +1)+\cos^2 { x }=-2\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)+1$$
$$-\sin^2{ x } -\sin{x} + \cos^2 { x }=-2\sin^2(x)-\sin{x} +1$$
$$-\sin^2{ x } + \cos^2 { x }=-2\sin^2(x)+1$$
$$\sin^2{x} + \cos^2{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1\iff \cos^2x=1-\sin^2x,$$we have$$\begin{align}-\sin x(\sin x+1)+\cos x\times\cos x&=-\sin^2x-\sin x+\cos^2x\\&=-\sin^2x-\sin x+(1-\sin^2x)\\&=-2\sin^2 x-\sin x+1.\end{align}$$